# How to declare multiple list <t> variables in one statement in c#

Tags: c#

How can I declare the following variables in one statement

```
List<Plane> availableAircrafts = new List<Plane>(); List<Plane> selectedAircrafts = new List<Plane>();
```

e.g. something like

```
List<Plane> availableAircrafts, selectedAircrafts = new List<Plane>();
```

I have tried the above but getting compiler error that the first variable is unused.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot or don't want to do it in two statements?

Comment: General practice is to declare them separately. Doing a single line is appropriate for things like `int` or `bool`, but even though this still works as the answers suggest, I'd just do it as two lines. There's never a time when this would actually gain you anything, and I'd call it a pretty significant risk to readability.

Comment: For readability and to avoid overlooking : Don't do that..

Comment: I'd expect the compiler "error" to actually be a warning... *are* you using the variable anywhere?

Comment: I'm getting the error with red squiggly (use of unassigned local variable availableAircrafts ) when I use this  "List<Plane> availableAircrafts ,selectedAircrafts = new List<Plane>();
            availableAircrafts.Add(new Plane { Id = 123, Name = "Antonov AN-2", NumberOfSeats = 12 });" And the only reason I asked this is to find the best practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the syntaxt point of view, without discussing if this is a good practice or not (see comments from @MatthewHaugen and @SriramSakthivel regarding that):

```
List<Plane> availableAircrafts = new List<Plane>(), selectedAircrafts = new List<Plane>();
```

So it is pretty much the same as for any other type.

---

And if the variable is unused, it is perhaps better to remove it, not to initialize.